# Is images in HTTP post request base64 encoded?

Tags: php, http, web, browser, httpclient

I am creating a HTTP client. I want to send images in a POST request. I was wondering weather I can embed binary data directly to the content or I have to base64 encode the image. Is there any specified or rule. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to base64 encode it, you can send binary data "as is".

Comment: User uploaded images or do you want to post the raw data?